# how to add symbol in the column value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

```
SELECT 
      Topics,
      [22] as Assgn1,
      [19] as Assgn2,
      [16],
      [17],
      [18],
      case  when  [17] = 0 or [17] IS null  then [18]*100 else (isnull([18],0) - [17])/[17]*100 end  AS PercentageImprove  

    from
    (
       SELECT 
         fltTotalMark as [TMark], 
         intAssessmentID as [assid] ,
         vchTopic as [Topics] 
       from ManageAssessment 
       WHERE intUserID=174 
    )AS S
    pivot
    (
      SUM(TMark)
      FOR assid IN ([22], [19], [16], [17], [18])
    )AS s
```

this is my sql code to generate a table,
here the table output:

```
Topics                |Assgn1   |Assgn2     |   16  |   17  |PercentageImprove|
NULL                  |8    3|  NULL|   3   |   0   |-100
Numbers               |NULL NULL|   2   |NULL   |   2   |200
Numbers(Unitary Method)|    NULL|   NULL|   1   |   NULL    |0
Occupations (people)   |    NULL|   NULL|   NULL|   1   |   -100
```

here PercentageImprove of percentage value i want show -100%,and the -100 value  show in red color and null i want to show as -,so any one help me to fix this problem..
Thank you..

Comment: i think you should remove `mysql` tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append percentage sign at end of case statement.

`CAST ( case  when  [17] = 0 or [17] IS null  then [18]*100 else (isnull([18],0) - [17])/[17]*100 end AS VARCHAR) + '%' AS PercentageImprove`

Also dont forget to cast the integer values returned from CASE statement to varchar otherwise sql server will try to add integer to percentage symbol and throw error.

As far as coloring values in red is concerned this is done at front end while displaying data.